# why does my loop doesnt work inside modal?

Tags: php, mysql, loops, for-loop, modal-dialog

I'm trying to display a set of buttons, that when clicked will display a table of data taken from the database. each button should display a different row, so I'm using 'for' to loop each button and 'modal' to display the table when clicked.

however right now when clicked all buttons are showing the same table, the content for row id=1. but if I remove the modal button, the data are shown correctly, just in tables one after another.

I've included the code for the loop and modal part, the part I think where the problem is. Can someone please take a look, and tell me where I should correct? If it's some other parts please let me know, and I'll provide it too. Thank you.

````
for($i = 1; $i<=10; $i++) {
?>
<?php
$sel_query="Select * from seating where id=$i;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sel_query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)
?>

<tr>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-circle btn-xl" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Table <?php echo $i ?><i class="fa fa-list"></i>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<div class="col-lg-6">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title">Table <?php echo $row["id"]; ?></h4>
<h4 class="card-title">Company: <?php echo $row["company"]; ?></h4>
<h4 class="card-title">Group: <?php echo $row["group"]; ?></h4>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table header-border"> ```
````

Comment: HTML element IDs should be unique, and _must be_ unique when referring to elements by ID in Javascript/jQuery

Comment: if your html is inside a for loop you will create that html in each iteration, so there you'll have 10 modals with the same id "myModal" as @PatrickQ said

Comment: thanks for the replies. is there any workaround for this? or any suggestion of another method to get this popup when click function other than modal?

Comment: Option 1) Make the IDs unique by appending `$i` (which is incremented by your loop)  Option 2) Use just one modal and fetch the appropriate content into the modal on click of the button.  Option 3) If your modal library allows it (not sure which one you're using) target based on something other than ID such as DOM traversal relative to the position of the clicked button.  I can't say exactly what that would look like since the HTML shown above isn't actually valid, and because I don't know if your modal library can handle that kind of targeting.